# How to make VPN only access the guest network

Tags: vpn, routing, guest-additions

So I recently setup a vpn network on Ubiquiti Unifi USG (using Remote User VPN) however, the vpn also connects to the main corporate network which I do not want. How can I make it so that the VPN can only connect to the Guest network only? (guest network is a separate network with a vlan. )

Thank you.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have the permission and authorizations, to make the required changes to the network configuration to acomplis this goal?  If you are not an Administrator with the necessary permissiona and authorizations, the actions you must perform to acomplish your goal, cannot be accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create firewall rules that restrict traffic outbound on the VPN interface from going anywhere except the VPN subnet, the guest network, and/or any other places you want to whitelist.

The USG will automatically route between all connected networks unless you explicitly put firewall rules in limiting network traversal.